# Haproxy logging final path after rewrite rule is processed

Tags: logging, url-rewriting, haproxy, httpbackend

In Haproxy 1.8.8, I am trying to log the final URI (not the incoming URI that was received in the frontend), In the backend section, i have proxy rewrite rule to change the path. I want that new path to be in the haproxy log. Here is the sample haproxy config file, i want to log `/defgh/v1/newpath` somewhere in the log. By default, http log-format captures only the request URI which in this below sample it wille `/abc/oldpath`. Can anyone please suggest how to capture the final path after rewrite rule is processed

sample haproxy config

```
frontend http-in
    option httplog
    bind *:80
    acl url_oldpath path_beg /abc/oldpath
    use_backend servers if url_oldpath

backend servers
    reqirep ^([^\ ]*)\ /abc/oldpath(.*) \1\ /defgh/v1/newpath\2
    server server1 myServerIP:80
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot log the response path in HAProxy:

```
http mode only | %HP  | HTTP request URI without query string (path)  | string
```

Only the request path is available to be logged. See the fields available to be logged [in the HAProxy documentation.](https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.8/configuration.html#8.2.4)

Is your backend server able to log the requests as it receives them? You could see the final path impacted by the rewrite there.